# Serving an image from my war directory?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets

I have a servlet which serves an image file which was stored in a blob. If the requested image can't be found, I'd like to server a static image I have included in my war directory. How do we do this? This is how I'm serving the blob images from the datastore:

```
public class ServletImg extends HttpServlet {
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
  {
    MyImgWrapper obj = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager().
      getObjectById(MyImgWrapper.class, 'xyz');
    if (obj != null) {
      resp.getOutputStream().write(obj.getBlob().getBytes());
      resp.getOutputStream().flush();
    }
    else {
      // Here I'd like to serve an image from my war file. 
      /war/img/missingphoto.jpg
    } 
  }
}
```

yeah I'm just not sure how to get the image bytes from the image in my war dir, or if there's some other way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other answers recommending [`ClassLoader#getResourceAsStream()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) are expecting that the image is located in the **classpath**. You can however also obtain the image from the **webcontent** using [`ServletContext#getResourceAsStream()`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)). The `ServletContext` is available in servlets by the inherited [`getServletContext()`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/GenericServlet.html#getServletContext()) method.

```
InputStream input = getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/img/missingphoto.jpg");
```

---

That said, reading and writing fully into/from a `byte[]` is not really memory efficient. Consider streaming through a small byte buffer (1~10KB) like so:

```
input = getServletContext().getResourceAsStream(path);
output = response.getOutputStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
for (int length = 0; (length = input.read(buffer)) > 0;) {
    output.write(buffer, 0, length);
}
```

Comment: Ok this works perfectly - I just wonder if splix's solution would give better performance (http redirect)? I guess the browser would have to make another request, so overall it would be slower? Thanks

Comment: The performance difference is negligible. At least, a redirect makes it impossible to set the response status to 404 (invoke `response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND);` before writing to the outputstream). The response status makes more sense to searchbots and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Follow Haveacafe's [tutorial](http://haveacafe.wordpress.com/2008/10/19/how-to-read-a-file-from-jar-and-war-files-java-and-webapp-archive/).

2nd result for Google: `java war file resource`.

Comment: Ah yeah that looks like what Stroboskop is also recommending, just not sure what the path should be for the resource?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use the class loader to retrieve the file.

```
ClassLoader classLoader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
InputStream in = classLoader.getResourceAsStream(fileNameInClasspath);
...
```

Comment: How do I know what 'fileNameInClasspath' should be though? The image path is: [war/img/test.jpg]

Answer (score 0):

Better way at this case will be simply return http redirect (status 301) to URL of this image.