# Servlet: How to build absolute path

Tags: java, servlets, path

I hava a java object, and am trying to do something like this:

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(imagePath)
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(is)
```

The problem is that I do not know how to get the value of `imagePath`.  I believe I need to build an absolute path to the file.  How is this possible when I am currently in a Java class, but my image file is under my webRoot folder?  I have tried `getResource(".").getPath()` but the path seems to include the `.war` in it which I dont think is possible.  Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We always use this way to get an `InputSteam`:

```
InputStream input = getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/images/image.jpg");
```

And if you really need the path of a file, you can also code like this:

```
File file = new File(getServletContext().getRealPath("/images/image.jpg"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the resource, you don't need the path. See this SOq:

- [Serving an image from my war directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3196792/serving-an-image-from-my-war-directory)